# How can I scale/stretch/skew a sprite from a sprite sheet with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing, sprite-sheet

**Some background:**
I am making a raycaster, well... was making. But I decided to change it up a bit. I started off going on creating the ray caster and decided it would be so much easier to just display an icon and stretch/skew it instead of just moving around a bunch of pixels.

**My question is:**
How can I scale/stretch/skew a sprite from a sprite sheet with javascript?

I basically am wanting to get a 16px by 16px image from a sprite image, and position it, scale it, turn it, and skew it with javascript. How should I go about doing that?

If this helps, I was thinking about connecting three versions of that image to give it the impression of a 3D block moving around in a 3D space without actually using 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [CSS3 transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform). Or use a hidden canvas element, apply a [transformation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) and then drawn it to the main canvas.

Answer (score 7):

Most probably the easiest way is to use the `background-size` css property. As most modern browsers (IE 9+, FF4+, Safari4+, Chrome3+) support it you can do the following:

html:

```
<div id="mySprite">
</div>
```

css:

```
#mySprite{
    height: 80px; /* 64px * 1.25 */
    width: 80px;  /* 64px * 1.25 */
    background-image:url(my.png);
    background-position: -0px -560px; /* pick specific one at -448px * 1.25 */
    background-size:640px 640px; /* scale image to 512px * 1.25 */
}
```

The spritesheet has sprites with size 64x64px on it and scales them to 80x80px.
See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgr5w/1/

As @Prusse said: you can use `transform: scale()` also but it has some drawbacks: browser support, additional position transformation, alignment with other elements may be broken:

```
#mySprite{
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    background-image:url(my.png);
    background-position: -0px -448px;
    transform:scale(1.25);
    /* additional to compensate the position shift */
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

see live example of the above two approaches here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgr5w/1/

Comment: great answer, and your comments in example one are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using the `drawImage` function on a canvas. The following example scales a 40x100 sprite to double 80x200 size.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=80 height=200>
    <script language="JavaScript">              
        function draw() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'http://gamemedia.wcgame.ru/data/2011-07-17/game-sprite-sheet.jpg';
            img.onload = function() {
                // (image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,40,100,0,0,80,200);
            }
        }

        draw();

    </script>
    </body>           
</html>
```

Comment: I actually did not take canvas into thought at all! Thanks! :D